# Spring-shell along with spring-boot NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-shell

I am trying to build a simple app using spring boot and spring shell . My pom.xml is like this:
[image]

I am getting the below error when trying to connect to the shell using putty

[image]

[image]

I am not able to get any pointers.

Putty I downloaded for windows. Trying connecting using user as username, password shown in console, port 2000. Logs says authentication successful. Still a NullPointerException
[image]

I am using jdk 1.8 only. Not jre.

Answer (score 0):

There are many open issues on this field right now. One of them is your same issue but specific for macOs, i do not have windows, but perhaps you can reproduce it same way and comment on that jira.

You can check it here:

https://jira.exoplatform.org/projects/CRASH/issues/CRASH-252?filter=allopenissues

If you want to use it, you should return to an older version better :)

Good luck!

Comment: I tired changing the version of sshd-core to 1.3.0 but I am getting the error classdefnotfound AbstractKeyPairProvider and am not sure what all libraries versions we need to change to get it working..